# Errores try , except python. Programa basico

Tags: python-3.x

Soy un padre de 40 y tantos años aprendiendo programación, no entiendo porque me entra este except:

```
#!usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
try:
    print ("Salario de un Trabajador")
    print ("")
    horas = float(input("Introduce las horas trabajadas:"))
    precio = float(input("A cuanto cuanto cobras las horas:"))
    salario = horas*precio
    print ("Tu sueldo es de:",salario)
except (ValueError,TypeError,IndexError):
    print ("Has Cometido el siguiente error:",sys.exc_info()[0]):
```

Pero en cambio no consigo que salte este cuando se introduce letras en vez de numeros:

```
import sys
print ("Calificaciones de un estudiante")
print ("")
nota = int(input("Introduce la nota obetenida en el curso:"))
try:
    if nota<0 or nota>10:
        print("La nota ingresada no es correcta.")
    if nota < 6:
        print ("Ha suspendido el curso")
    elif nota >=6 and nota < 7:
        print ("Ha obtenido un SUFICIENTE")
    elif nota >=7 and nota < 8:
        print ("Ha obtenido un BIEN")
    elif nota >=8 and nota < 11:
        print ("Ha obtenido un NOTABLE")
    elif nota >=9 and nota < 8:
        print ("Ha obtenido un SOBRESALIENTE")
except (ValueError,TypeError,IndexError):
    print("Has cometido un error al ingresar la nota.")
    print("Has Cometido el siguiente error:",sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Espero vuestra ayuda para seguir aprendiendo, tampoco hace falta la solución solo con que me expliquen el porque, intentaré solucinarlo, si no ya volvere a postear.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Saludos fijate que en el primer ejercicio de Salario de un Trabajador posees un error "print ("Has Cometido el siguiente error:",sys.exc_info()[0]):" estan demas los dos puntos, lo he probado retirando ello y funciona perfecto..!!

Comment: @Diego Avila con números funciona, pero con cadenas no, y como la excepción no está contemplada, salta un `NameError`.
Prueba a modificar esta línea `except (ValueError,TypeError,IndexError, NameError)`  y así entrará por el `except`
Por supuesto los `:` del `except` sobran.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes la conversión fuera del bloque `try:`, por lo que si falla no ejecutará el `except` asociado. Prueba a meterlo:

```
...
try:
    nota = int(input("Introduce la nota obtenida en el curso:"))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

En el primero ejercicio tienes **DOS PUNTOS** extras justo en el **print** de tu **except** lo tienes asi:

```
 print ("Has Cometido el siguiente error:",sys.exc_info()[0]):
```

deberia ser asi:

```
 print ("Has Cometido el siguiente error:",sys.exc_info()[0])
```

el resultado: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el segundo ejercicio como ya te comentaron la conversión debes hacerla dentro del **try** para que en el caso de que surja un error vaya por tus excepciones realizadas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero te sirva..!!